# BeautifulSoup trying to get text from wrapped divs but empty or "none" is being returned

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Here is a picture (sorry) of the HTML that I am trying to parse:
[image: HTML of the sports page with stats]

I am using this line:

```
home_stats = soup.select_one('div', class_='statText:nth-child(1)').text
```

Thinking that I'd get the 1st child of the class statText and the outcome would be 53%.

But it's not. I get "Loading..." and none of the data that I was trying to use and display.

The full code I have so far:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

home_team = soup.find('div', class_='tname-home').a.text
away_team = soup.find('div', class_='tname-away').a.text
home_score = soup.select_one('.current-result .scoreboard:nth-child(1)').text
away_score = soup.select_one('.current-result .scoreboard:nth-child(2)').text
print("The home team is " + home_team, "and they scored " + home_score)
print()
print("The away team is " + away_team, "and they scored " + away_score)

home_stats = soup.select_one('div', class_='statText:nth-child(1)').text
print(home_stats)
```

Which currently does print the hone and away team and the number of goals they scored. But I can't seem to get any of the statistical content from this site.

My output plan is to have:

```
[home_team] had 53% ball possession and [away_team] had 47% ball possession
```

However, I would like to remove the "%" symbols from the parse (but that's not essential). My plan is to use these numbers for more stats later on, so the % symbol gets in the way.

Apologies for the noob question - this is the absolute beginning of my Pythonic journey. I have scoured the internet and StackOverflow and just can not find this situation - I also possibly don't know exactly what I am looking for either.

Thanks kindly for your help! May your answer be the one I pick as "correct" ;)

Comment: If you only get `Loading...`, are you sure the website you're trying to scrap doesn't require some JS to load the data you need ?

Comment: It would be helpful if u provide the url of the page.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that [this](https://www.scoreboard.com/en/match/SO3Fg7NR/#match-statistics;0) is the website that u r tryna scrape, here is the complete code to scrape all the stats:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver 
import pandas as pd 

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')

driver.get('https://www.scoreboard.com/en/match/SO3Fg7NR/#match-statistics;0')

pg = driver.page_source #Gets the source code of the page
driver.close()

soup = BeautifulSoup(pg,'html.parser') #Creates a soup object

statrows = soup.find_all('div',class_ = "statTextGroup") #Finds all the div tags with class statTextGroup -- these div tags contain the stats

#Scrapes the team names
teams = soup.find_all('a',class_ = "participant-imglink")

teamslst = []
for x in teams:
    team = x.text.strip()
    if team != "":
        teamslst.append(team)

stats_dict = {}

count = 0
for x in statrows:
   txt = x.text 
   final_txt = ""
   stat = ""
   alphabet = False
   percentage = False
   
   #Extracts the numbers from the text
   for c in txt:
       if c in '0123456789':
           final_txt+=c
       else:
           if alphabet == False:
               final_txt+= "-"
               alphabet = True
           if c != "%":
               stat += c
           else:
               percentage = True 
   values = final_txt.split('-')

   #Appends the values to the dictionary
   for x in values:
       if stat in stats_dict.keys():
           if percentage == True:
               stats_dict[stat].append(x + "%")
           else:
               stats_dict[stat].append(int(x))
               
       else:
           if percentage == True:
               stats_dict[stat] = [x + "%"]
           else:
               stats_dict[stat] = [int(x)]
               
   count += 1 
   if count == 15:
       break

index = [teamslst[0],teamslst[1]]

#Creates a pandas DataFrame out of the dictionary
df = pd.DataFrame(stats_dict,index = index).T 
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                  Burnley Southampton
Ball Possession       53%         47%
Goal Attempts          10           5
Shots on Goal           2           1
Shots off Goal          4           2
Blocked Shots           4           2
Free Kicks             11          10
Corner Kicks            8           2
Offsides                2           1
Goalkeeper Saves        0           2
Fouls                   8          10
Yellow Cards            1           0
Total Passes          522         480
Tackles                15          12
Attacks               142         105
Dangerous Attacks      44          29
```

Hope that this helps!

P.S: I actually wrote this code for a different question, but I didn't post it as an answer was already posted! But I didn't know that it would come in handy now! Anyways, I hope that my answer does what u need.